# Azure Notification Hub registration Time To Live

Tags: .net, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

By default registration TTL is set to a lifetime (10,675,199 days).
How can I change it and control it?

[image]

Haven't found clues on management portal, .Net description, powershell automation script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/push-notification-hub-telemetry-expiry-update/) it is configured on hub level via [RegistrationTtl property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubdescription.registrationttl?view=azurenotificationhubs-1.0.7#Microsoft_Azure_NotificationHubs_NotificationHubDescription_RegistrationTtl):

```
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString("connectionstring");
NotificationHubDescription hub = namespaceManager.GetNotificationHub("foo");
hub.RegistrationTtl = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
namespaceManager.UpdateNotificationHub(hub);
```